# Using a class field in another fields

Tags: python, class, django-models, field

I have a field in a class that depends on another field in the same class but I have a problem to code:

`class myclass(models.Model):
    nation = [('sp', 'spain'), ('fr', 'france')]
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=nation)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=name)`

I want to put name = [('ro', 'rodrigo'), ('ra', 'raquel')] if nation = spain and  name = [('lu', 'luis'), ('ch', 'chantal')] if nation = france.

How I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is change the view that the user sees. What you have above is the underlying DB model which is the wrong place for this sort of feature.

In addition (assuming this is a web application), you will probably need to do it in Javascript, so you can change the set of allowed names as soon as the user changes the nationality field.

Comment: Thank you, but instead using limit_choices_to is it possible? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

Comment: Not sure how how you want this to appear to the user. You could set it to a callable, however the callable will only get invoked when the form is created and the form is validated. If you want some sort of drop down menu to pick the options available, this drop down menu won't get updated when you change the nationality. If however you want the name field to be rendered as a text box, and require the user to (guess?) a valid option, it might work.